# single Observer iterpretation, experiment design

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, observers

I am thinking of an interpretation of QM in which there is a single Observer (O). That is, its mind's history is marking a special path on the many-world graph, which we identify with reality. This does not assume any form of physical uniqueness of (O), and realities exist where other observers become (O) at all times.

I think this interpretation is falsifiable, and trying to design an experiment which would prove that a particular person is (O) or not. That is, I am looking for a test which involves a human observer, and - if this interpretation is true and reality is the production of (O)'s mind - would produce the same results for all 7 billion humans on Earth but not for (O), with significant statistics.

One obvious test would be to use potential observers in a two-slit experiment and observe interference patterns formed by the observers themselves. The prediction is that (O) would not form interference patterns, but all other observers do. This test is obviously unrealistic at many levels, and I am looking for alternatives which are practically viable.

I am sure I am not the first to raise this, but could not find any references. If you aware of anything similar, please share.

Comment: The many worlds part of your theory could be falsified by showing that a wavefunction collapses when a quantum system is coupled to a large mass, but still isolated from the environment.

Comment: MWI is on the limits. It would be hard to validate your protocol since one can place anything that disturbs in the hidden versions of the reality, with no access to the outcomes. Otherwise, you don't need human observers, any interaction with a sequence which ends on an observable do the job.